# Writing a bash script to find all files in a directory that start with a, and do nothing if one exist

Tags: linux, bash, file

So I have to find all the files in the directory that start with the letter a, and list them out. This is pretty easy by doing

```
cd some_directory

for file in a*; do 
    echo "$file"
done
```

However I want that if there are *no* files present that match a*, then the for loop will not run at all. Currently, if this is the case then the shell will echo

```
a*
```

Is there a way to do this? Thank you

Comment: Wait...  Why `echo $a` ?  There is no `$a` variable in the code you put here.  Do you mean `$file` or something else?

Comment: Yes I mean `$file` my mistake with a typo

Comment: Dude, I cannot keep up with all the edits you are making.  Work on your code, when you get the result you want / you identify the problem, post again.

Comment: `ls a*` is all what you want. No need for loops!

Comment: I posted my code but this @Rafael keeps changing it into ways that I did not want. The only original error I had was `$file`, but my code was then changed to `$(ls ./a*)` against my choice. This is right now how it is and is meant to be. Please don't downvote I was not in control of many of the edit

Comment: @Rafael Please don't edit code in questions like you did, see [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code). Specifically: "don't change the code logic or functionality".

Answer (score 0):

Your text is opposite of your title, in my answer below I've assumed the text is your intention and your title is incorrect:

globs can be made to act like this with the bash shell option "nullglob":

`shopt -s nullglob`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `find` and ignore errors by piping `stderr` to `/dev/null`

```
for file in $(find a* 2>/dev/null); do 
    echo "$file"
done
```